# One to Many mapping models inside DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Currently I am new to MVC and practicing with some demo applications.

I have 2 models.

Employee - (with data members employeeId,name,gender,city,deptId)
Department - (with data members id,name,Collection employees )

I have put these two classes inside a context class inheriting from DbContext.

Problem is when I try to get employee data based on deptId , it throws error that department_Id column is not defined. If I remove the employees data member from Department then everything works fine. What exactly is happening here, why is it automatically adding a column, and how to tackle it?

Comment: show us your classes definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `deptId` property to your Employee class. Just add a `navigation property` like this:

```
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

And your Department class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Then Entity Framework will create all necessary relationships automatically for you.

For more informatin about Navigation Properties take a look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx